# Selenium find by name works on some websites but not others

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to go to a website and add string to an input field. The following code works on the stack overflow website:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                          options=options)

driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
driver.maximize_window()


num = "17885"
input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
input.send_key(num)
```

But if I change the URL and the NAME to a different corresponding website I get a NoSuchElementException. I am very sure that I have entered the correct NAME tag. Why is this happening?

Comment: Specifying which website and which name aren’t working might help you get an answer. “This code works except when it doesn’t” isn’t much to go by.

Comment: That info belongs in the question, not the comments

Comment: You can mention two xpaths, like a driver.findelement(By.xpath("  one browser element PAth")  || ("  Other browser element path  "));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your selector is correct, there could be a number of reasons why finding an element (either by name or any other selector) might not be working:

**Timing or Synchronisation issues**: The element is not yet present on the DOM or is not yet interact-able.

**Element is not visible or obscured**: Another element could be obscuring the element you're trying to interact with, or the element is not within the viewable area on the page.

**iFrame issues**: The element you're trying to interact with is nested within an iframe.

In the example you've provided, the website you're trying to access has an iframe (you can verify this by searching on 'iframe' in the devtools). When trying to access an element within an iframe you'll have to first switch the context to that iframe. In your case you could use something like the following (with the caveat that this is a particularly simple example, and it'd usually be better practise to reference iframes by a selector other than the tag name):

```
# Store iframe web element.
iframe = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'iframe')

# Switch to selected iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# Find the element in the iframe
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'field_name')
```

Also, please note that if you're required to interact with some other element **outside** of the iframe after you've switched context to the iframe arleady, then you'd have to switch back to the default context before proceeding:

```
# switch back to default content
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

More on working with iframes in Selenium [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/).

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is in an IFRAME. Switch context to that IFRAME and your code should work fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url = "https://www.mybkexperience.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "IFRAME")))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ChoiceStructure > input"))).send_keys("test")
```